# Building a pkcs7 signature in php aleady knowing the signature

Tags: php, digital-signature, pkcs#7

My goal is to sign pdf and e-mails on my server, using an USB token on the client side.

So I would like to build a PKCS7 signature in PHP, but the signature will be obtained from the USB token, that's why I can't use openssl pkcs7 implementation.

I have seen something that could be a solution, using Bouncy Castle : [create PKCS7 with presigned data using bouncy castle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39378249/create-pkcs7-with-presigned-data-using-bouncy-castle), but I'd like not to use an external implementation.

I have searched for a library that could build the pkcs7 from certificate chain and the signature but I haven't found anything.